# Using a Method to Change the Value of a Static Variable of an Object in Java

Tags: java, methods, static, setter

I am trying to create an ATM in Java using methods. I am trying to call methods that change the variable (total) of the object (balance). I have successfully created the object and set its starting value but I can't figure out how to create a method that alters that methods. I am not sure how setters and getters would apply because everything is static. Any suggestions?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr6iM.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! Please post your code as text inside a code block in your question (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks). This will make it easier to read and copy/paste to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your setter and getter could look like in the following snippet. I set total to private as it should only be accessible by the setter and getter functions. You can then set your value by startVal.setTotal(100);

```
class balance {

    private int total;

    int getTotal() {
        return total;
    }

    void setTotal(int total) {
        this.total = total;
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {

private static Scanner in;
private static Balance balance;

public static void main (String[] args) {
  in = new Scanner(System.in);
  balance = new Balance();

  while(true) {
    System.out.println("Main menu:");
    System.out.println("1. Check Balance");
    System.out.println("2. Withdraw");
    System.out.println("3. Deposite");
    System.out.println("4. Exit");

    int n = in.nextInt();

    switch (n) {
      case 1 : displayBalance();
               break;
      case 2 : withdraw();
               break;
      case 3 : deposite();
               break;
      default : return;
    }
  }
}

private static void displayBalance() {
  System.out.println(balance.getBalance());
}

private static void withdraw() {
  double currentBalance = balance.getBalance();

  System.out.println("Enter amount to be withdrawn : ");
  double withdrawAmount = in.nextDouble();
  double balanceAfterWithdraw = currentBalance - withdrawAmount;

  if (balanceAfterWithdraw > 0) {
    balance.setBalance(balanceAfterWithdraw);
    System.out.println(withdrawAmount + " withdrawn.");
    System.out.println("Your new balance is : " + balance.getBalance());
  } else
    System.out.println("You don't have sufficient balance !!!");
}

private static void deposite() {
  double currentBalance = balance.getBalance();

  System.out.println("Enter amount to deposit : ");
  double depositeAmount = in.nextDouble();
  double balanceAfterDeposit = currentBalance + depositeAmount;

  balance.setBalance(balanceAfterDeposit);
  System.out.println(depositeAmount + " deposited.");
  System.out.println("Your new balance is : " + balance.getBalance());
  }
}


public class Balance {

  private double balance;

  public Balance() {
    this.balance = 100;
  }

  public double getBalance() {
    return balance;
  }

  public void setBalance(double amount) {
    this.balance = amount;
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If you have a second to explain things, could I  ask a few questions? I am trying to give the program an initial balance of 100 but I cannot figure out where to insert:                                  'balance.setBalance(100);'                                                    
  in the code in order to set the value.

Comment: Create a constructor that will set 100 on object creation like 
```public Balance() { this.balance = 100; }```
I am editing the code with constructor.